# elasticsearch mapping for keywords

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, elasticsearch-mapping

I want to index document keywords as array datatype, not a string, something like: `keywords:['key1', 'key2',...]` and from elasticsearch documentation 
you can have keywords field as a string:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "tags": {
          "type":  "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

what should I do?

Comment: what is your reason to use keyword instead of string here?

Comment: each document has 4 to 8 keywords, to map them as a string, I have 2 options, first to pack them together(something like "key1||key2||key3||..."  which isn't efficient for search query(or at least that is what I think ) and the 2nd way is to have 8 text field as key1, key2, key3... which  this one is also not efficient since I have 4 million document and its  gonna be more , what do you think?

Comment: let me add this that I am okay with "key1||key2||key3||..." if  somehow configure elasticsearch mapping to detect each one of them as keywords

Answer (score 1):

In elasticsearch documentation there is a "Array datatype", could you use this mapping?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html

Comment: it worked this way, but not as keyword data type,  I am not sure which way is better, to have an array of keywords data type or just have an array